# Disableing Android listview

Tags: android, listview, clickable, scrollable

I have a view with a listview and several other views including a button and a few edittexts. I want the listview to be scrollable but not clickable after i press the button.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a field, something like:

```
private boolean clicked = false;
```

I would then go into the onClick method and add something like

```
    if(!clicked){
//Do Stuff on the click
    clicked = true;
}
else if(clicked){
//do nothing
}
```

then to accept a click again you would first have to set clicked to false again, and then continue to accept clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You need disable the clicklisteners for the listview by calling setOnClickListener to null , @Aaron Decker's solution is good too :-)